# Health insurance out of registration period for pregnant woman

Tags: obstetrics, health-insurance

My wife and I are residents of NC. Yesterday , we just realized that my wife is pregnant and unfortunately she doesn't have a health insurance. Medicaid is an option we are going to pursue but i am trying to get her a health insurance as soon as possible for now.

It seems most health insurance companies won't accept us out of registration period unless we have a qualifying event (getting pregnant is not one of them).

I really could use any suggestions about what my options here 
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while it's not strictly a request for health advice, no one here can provide health insurance advice.